# using awk to extract filed from an url

Tags: awk

I have a file that has the following urls

1. http://10.32.43.211:25280/sherlock/store/pyy/debug? q=puma+shoes+shorts+men & shorts = true & cash-enable = false & pincode = 560102
2. http://10.32.43.211:25280/sherlock/store/poq/debug? q=nike+shoes+shorts+women & shorts = true & cash-enable = false & pincode = 560102

I want to extract the following (using awk , not gawk)
    q=puma shoes shorts men
    q=addidas shoes shorts men

I need to know how to replace the '+' with blank after getting
    q=nike+shoes+shorts+women

I tried

```
awk -F '?' '{ print $2 }' urls_details, but the printing everything after the ?, 
q=puma+shoes+shorts+men & shorts = true & cash-enable = false & pincode = 560102

 q=addidas+shoes+shorts+men & shorts = true & cash-enable = false & pincode = 560102

q=nike+shoes+shorts+women & shorts = true & cash-enable = false & pincode = 560102
```

how can I retrieve just the fields before the & , 
q=nike+shoes+shorts+women

Comment: @ARCHANA, Welcome to SO, thanks for showing what you have tried with samples. Try to wrap all samples of files of input and output into CODE TAGS too, cheers and enjoy learning on this wonderful site named SO :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that your actual Input_file is same as shown sample(s) if this is the case then following may help you here.

```
awk 'match($0,/http:\/\/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+:[0-9]+\/.*\? /){gsub(/+/," ",$2);print $2}' Input_file
```

OR(a non-one liner form of solution):

```
awk '
match($0,/http:\/\/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+:[0-9]+\/.*\? /){
  gsub(/+/," ",$2);
  print $2
}' Input_file
```

Regex in `match` function of `awk` will check if a line is having a URL starting from http till `?` if it matches then print the 2nd column of that line.